# Prevent Wkhtmltopdf from outputting Status

Tags: php, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am using the [WKHTMLTOPDF](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) for converting html pages to pdf. I wrote the below code.

```
system("wkhtmltopdf http://localhost/advisory_system/frontend/index.php/Analysis/fpdf /opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf_testo/test1/pdf_final_testA_$i.pdf  2>&1");
```

While using the above script in my PHP script it outputs the STATUS, like:

> Loading pages (1/6) [> ] 0% [======> ] 10% [=========> ] 15%
>   [==========> ] 18% [============> ] 21% [=================> ] 29%
>   [========================> ] 41% [==========================> ] 44%
>   [==============================> ] 50%
>   [============================================================] 100%
>   Counting pages (2/6)
>   [============================================================] Object
>   1 of 1 Resolving links (4/6)
>   [============================================================] Object
>   1 of 1 Loading headers and footers (5/6) Printing pages (6/6) [> ]
>   Preparing [=====> ] Page 1 of 11 [==========> ] Page 2 of 11
>   [================> ] Page 3 of 11 [=====================> ] Page 4 of
>   11 [===========================> ] Page 5 of 11
>   [================================> ] Page 6 of 11
>   [=====================================> ] Page 7 of 11
>   [===========================================> ] Page 8 of 11`
>   [================================================> ] Page 9 of 11
>   [======================================================> ] Page 10 of
>   11 [============================================================] Page
>   11 of 11 Done

How can I prevent output of this type of status by wkhtmltopdf?

**Version is:  0.12.1 (with patched qt)**

Comment: Isn't there a `--help` mode mentioning the quiet flag? And you're just mapping stderr to stdout, but don't redirect the latter to `null`.

Comment: @mario I don't have found any --help there and can you tell me how can i later redirects it to null.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the Solution, By Using the [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function of PHP.It Just execute the command and don't send the out put while [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function outputs the execution output.
So my script looks like now :

```
exec("wkhtmltopdf http://localhost/advisory_system/frontend/index.php/Analysis/fpdf /opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf_testo/test1/pdf_final_testA_$i.pdf  2>&1");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stop wkhtmltopdf from outputting the status by setting the default configurations and verbose configurations as follows:

```
config.default_options = {
 :quiet => true,
 :debug_javascript => false
}
config.verbose = false
```